# Create Android Quiz App

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android development. I just saw a tutorial on how to insert data in the db. Here's the link: [Using SQLite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aui-kFuXFYE#!)

However, I don't want to insert data every time my app starts. I want to insert it once and retrieve multiple times.

Meaning, the data is not inserted via the app. Does someone know a tutorial on how to do that ?

Comment: everytime how it is going to be inserted?? If you are firing insert query then it can. Durig your application developement insert data once. and then after.. only retrieve where required.

Comment: SQLite data usually persists between app launches. You can insert once and retrieve it later, unless the database or app is deleted. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1):

You can create one method by which you can copy your data from assests folder to your device data folder when application runs on device.

So make one method for doing this task whenever application starts then this method runs automatically and save your data to your device.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is,

1. Download `Firefox SQLite Manager Plugin` and do all the stuffs you want like adding data, creating table, columns etc.
2. Save that file into Android `assets` folder.
3. In the `MainActivity.class`, write a code to check whether the database exists or not. Mostly, the database file will be stored in `/data/data/YOUR-PACKAGE/databases/`
4. If it doesn't exists, copy the `database file` from `assets` and place it in `/data/data/YOUR-PACKAGE/databases/` & if it exists don't do anything.
5. Then use `select` query and retrieve the data using `sqlite` methods.